# Nhibernate SQL Server CE Bulkupdate

Tags: nhibernate, batch-file, sql-server-ce, bulk

Is there a way to bulk insert/update records in a SQL Server CE database using Nhibernate?

Comment: You can use my SqlCeBulkCopy library, but it is not related to nHibernate

Comment: Is there a way i can use this with Nhibernate? @ErikEJ

Comment: It is just .NET code, so you can use it with any .NET code...

Comment: In the sample code i see it needs DataReader. Can i pass List of object.

Answer (score 0):

ErikEJ s code might be more performant but to answer the question:

It is possible to Insert a lot of data using `IStatelessSession.Insert()`